# Do variables persist in an app if the home button is pressed?

Tags: ios, arrays

I have an app which allows users to send messages to each other. The messages are stored locally on the user's phone's SQL library. I have an array (of all the conversations) of arrays (of the individual conversations) which the phone actually uses to populate label values. This array of arrays, `[[pulledMessage]]`, is populated from the SQL by the app's `didFinishLaunching` and works fine. I can write any new messages to the user's SQL library, and also update that array. My question is, do I have to reload the SQL data into the array on `viewDidLoad` of the app (since new messages will be *added* to the conversations but wouldn't be loaded *from* SQL since the loading is in `didFinishLaunching`). This doesn't normally create an issue (since populating the SQL library at the same time as updating the array is basically the same thing as loading from SQL into the array), but what happens when the user "closes" the app. I do not mean hard closing, like terminating it. I mean like hitting the home button and having it still in the background. Does the `[[pulledMessage]]` persist so that I do not need to rerun its population (and therefore put the loading into the `viewDidLoad`), or do I need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is suspended (by tapping the home button), and the user restarts it, the app will application will generally just enter foreground state again and everything in memory is still there. But, in that case, `viewDidLoad` isn't called anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

The only time that you'll see `didFinishLaunching` and `viewDidLoad` being called again is if the app was to be terminated for some reason. And it's not just if the user explicitly terminated your app. This can also happen if your app is suspended, the user starts another app that requires so much memory that your app is jettisoned by the OS. Once your app is suspended, it might be killed due to factors outside your control, so you should handle this gracefully. But often it will not be terminated but rather will stay in memory and these methods won't get called again.

So, bottom line, if you see `didFinishLaunching` and `viewDidLoad` sorts of methods getting called, that means that the app was completely restarted and you'll want to reload your data structures in this case.

---

Just so you can see the app lifecycle in action, I added `os_log` statements to the key events of an app's life-cycle. I used the unified logging system (see WWDC 2016 [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) video) so I could observe the behavior from the macOS "Console" app when not running the app from Xcode; running it from Xcode can change app lifecycle behavior. I then watched these in the macOS "Console" app when I started the app from the device (not Xcode). This is what I saw:

User starts app for the first time:

```
debug   14:46:25.256978 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    AppDelegate didFinishLaunching
debug   14:46:25.258476 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    ViewController  viewDidLoad
debug   14:46:25.258550 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    ViewController  viewWillAppear
debug   14:46:25.261261 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    ViewController  viewDidAppear
debug   14:46:25.300246 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive
```

The user presses the home button:

```
debug   14:46:46.996735 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive
debug   14:46:48.032994 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground
```

And the user restarts the app by tapping on the icon:

```
debug   14:47:09.263330 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground
debug   14:47:09.274849 -0700   MyApp   com.domain.MyApp    AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive
```

Note, it didn't call `didFinishLaunching` or `viewDidLoad`.

---

FYI, it's probably apparent from the above, but this is the app delegate code to generate those logging messages:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: "com.domain.MyApp", category: "AppDelegate")

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        os_log("didFinishLaunching", log: log, type: .debug)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        os_log("applicationWillResignActive", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        os_log("applicationDidEnterBackground", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        os_log("applicationWillEnterForeground", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        os_log("applicationDidBecomeActive", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        os_log("applicationWillTerminate", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

}
```

And the view controller code:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: "com.domain.MyApp", category: "ViewController")

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        os_log("viewDidLoad", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        os_log("viewWillAppear", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        os_log("viewDidAppear", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        os_log("viewWillDisappear", log: log, type: .debug)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        os_log("viewDidDisappear", log: log, type: .debug)
    }
}
```

---

I might also refer you to the [Execution States for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) and [App Termination](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW7) sections in the *App Programming Guide for iOS: The App Life Cycle* for more information.